# ModelLayer(Context appContext) Singleton Constructor in Android...what does the following code with comments exactly do?

Tags: android

In the model layer of the Android project I am learning from the Big nerd Ranch Android Programming book, there is a specific singleton - model layer class, which goes like this:

```
 public class ModelLayerClass          
 {
 private static ModelLayerClass class_instance;   //its a clear singleton here ! 
 private Context context_instance;

 private ModelLayerClass(Context appContext)  //why this parameter is being passed?
 {
 context_instance = appContext;             //how this helps  here ?    
 }
 public static ModelLayerClass get(Context c)
 {
 if(class_instance=null)
  {
     class_instance = new ModelLayerClass(c.getApplicationContext());
   }
return class_instance;
 }
}
```

When I went through the book, it was saying that, it is common practice in Android to have a Context parameter which allows the singleton to "start activities", access project resources, find your apps private storage and more.....doesnt the classes in our project have a default access to all of these (except for starting activities). Can anyone direct me to proper online resources or could give me a good explanation about this...thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your activity, you do have access to everything within your application, but generally through the use of context.  Here's the Android documentation for [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

For example, when you write

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
```

You only have access to the startActivity method because your Activity class is extends Activity.  If you want to start an activity from a singleton or from another class or anything like that, you need to have a Context to start an activity.

For example, if you wanted to start the same activity above, but from outside of your Activity class, you must have a context:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NewActivity.class));
```

Same goes for any number of other things you might want to do outside of your Activity class.

Accessing resources:

```
Bitmap imageFromRes = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

Creating new Android views:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
```

Basically, Context is a good "catch-all" parameter that allows your non-Android classes to still utilize methods that you would use in Android classes (like Activity, Service, Dialog, etc).

Comment: Precisely explanation I was looking for ....Thank you ! clears a lot of my questions ! :)) and if possible can you elaborate the second line of code in your answer, the context class over there...is it referring to the getApplicationContext()?

Comment: It could, but it doesn't have to refer to getApplicationContext().  You can always access the application context by calling context.getApplicationContext();

Comment: im sorry, but Im confused again does it go this way... context.getApplicationContext.startActivity(...) == calling context.startActivity(...)

Comment: Both are essentially the same thing and both should work just fine, but you will generally just do context.startAcitivity(...)